# Fos UserBundle with yaml - doctrine schema update

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml, fosuserbundle

I wanted to use `FOSUserBundle`, installed it and first set it up with annotations, but because I had other entities i choose yaml.

I did as it was written in the documentation, created the yaml file and added some fields that I needed. I generated the entity itself and then in the php file extended the `BaseUser` class.

That part is working, because when i first wanted to update SQL it threw the error to change to protected or public, but after update, the base FOS fields are not in the DB.

Here is the User.orm.yml

```
Plastic\PublicBundle\Entity\User:
type:  entity
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [setCreated, setModified]
    preUpdate: [setModified]
oneToMany:
    albums:
        targetEntity: Album
        mappedBy: user
    images:
        targetEntity: Image
        mappedBy: user
table: users
id:
    id:
        type: integer
        generator:
            strategy: AUTO
fields:
    firstName:
        type: string
        length: 50
    lastName:
        type: string
        length: 50
    gender:
        type: boolean
    dateOfBirth:
        type: date
```

And the User.php entity with the first relevant part:

```
<?php

namespace Plastic\PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

/**
 * @var integer
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $firstName;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $lastName;
    /**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->albums = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->images = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}
```

In my config.yml for ORM the automapping is set to true.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
```

try using

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
```

I.e, because you're using orm, you have to use the Entity base class, not the Model base class. I got stuck with this a while also, but the above change made things work again.

Comment: Tried but didn't worked, and i think now there is no difference in the dev-master branch, cause entity / document is also just extending the model, and in the description on fosusrbundle is also saying for sql,mongo use the Model class one

Comment: are you using MongoDB or ORM? because your code suggest that you're using ORM... Yes both the Document and Entity classes are extending Model. I'm thinking it's just to namespace them differently so the library can determine which method you're using.

Comment: I'm using ORM, but i tried out your answer and it didn't worked. I managed to get it work like i create everything in my yml file and then the insert was good, but that's not the best solution, just a workaround.

Comment: FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User is deprecated in newer versions of FOS User Bundle